# Commit with TortoiseSVN wont work due to missing privileges?

Tags: tortoisesvn, commit, privileges

I set up a SVN and I am using TortoiseSVN as client. I imported my project to the SVN and now I made changes which I want to commit. So I click commit to do that, what I get is:

Access denied to c:\users\username

Why is that? I already searched google, but found nothing? Any ideas? I am running that in Win7 64bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is because, your svn server does not allow your user to commit, please goto your server management and put the access for the user, you have to set a rule for the user.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that? I am on my server now, whats next? Thanks!

Comment: what server apllication is installed there? is it collabnet?

Comment: Go to your repositories and then navigate to access rule

Comment: I used the 1ClickSetup found here: http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/. Looking at my service list, I see a SVNService by Clansoft. Does that tell you something?

Comment: [groups]
gurus = user1, user2 
project1 = admin, todi, som, subhojit
project2= admin, todi, som, subhojit

[/]
* = rw

[project1:/]
* = 
@project1 = rw

Comment: Login to your account, can you see any where set rukle or access rules? If yes then follow the step of my 2nd answer

Comment: I am logged in to the server, but are we talking about windows functionality here? Should I right click my repository and look for it?

Comment: **The solution was to install TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, instead of 1.7.3 :)**

Answer (score 1):

```
[groups]
gurus = user1, user2 
project1 = user1, user2 
project2= user1, user2 

[/]
* = rw
[project1:/]
* = 
@project1 = rw
[project2:/]
* = 
@project2 = rw
```

Set your rulr like this

Comment: Yes, ok, but where? In the passwd file?

Comment: See it where? On the client or on the server?